# Why declare variables with shift operator?

Tags: java, variable-assignment

I read some open source codes and often come across variable declaration like this:

```
private static final int MAX_LITERAL = 1 << 5;
```

This is 2^5 (32) and is much more readable for some people to declare as "32" than  "1 << 5". Any good explanation to why it is done using bit shifting operator?

Comment: The operation shows how the number was devised. Perhaps it's being used for bit operations?

Comment: But then why not just write `0b00100000`?

Comment: I've voted to close - this question will provoke debate not factual answers.

Comment: @ImreKerr what about 0b00010000000000000000? Can you say which bit is set in this case?

Comment: @ImreKerr this is supported only starting with Java 7, and just imagine "decoding" 1 << 31 written in binary

Comment: It's used when defining bit masks, where the important thing is not the value but the bit position, and the fact that only one bit is being set. If you have a succession of values `1 << 0, 1 << 1, 1 << 2`, etc, it is easy to see that those conditions are being satisified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for readability purposes, most likely that number is used in bitwise operations.

Although it is indeed 32, maybe you'll see the reasoning if you don't think of it as `32`, but as `a number with the fifth bit set, and the others unset`.

Comment: I use it for various constants, for example buffer size. It emphasizes that I'm using a "round" number (in binary), which is a good thing in many situations.